# Windows10 Shortcuts from start-menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts

On `windows10`, I'm not able to make `shortcuts` from the **start-menu to desktop** by dragging the program's icon, I also don't have any context menu option to achieve this.
Am I missing something here?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on the **Acrobat Reader DC** entry on your **Start Menu,** select **More,** and then **Open File Location**.

This will open the folder containing the shortcuts. You can now copy this shortcut to your desktop.

The Windows 10 Start Menu is built "dynamically" from content in a few locations, and is no longer just a visual representation of a specific set of folders as it has been in past versions of Windows. This means that the items in the Start Menu are not the actual shortcut files themselves, but are more like representations of the shortcuts.

For most programs the shortcuts actually still exist, you just have to get to the actual shortcut to copy it to your desktop or elsewhere.

Comment: I don't have that option.

Comment: What do you get when you right-click on other items in the Start Menu? Do any of them have a "More" option?

Comment: `rate and view` and `share` only

Comment: Interesting. What build of Win10 are you running? Were you able to find the folders mentioned in @Run5K's answer?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro Education

Comment: No, what version: 1507, 1511, 1607 (Anniversary), Insider Edition, etc?

Comment: 1607 Anniversary - 14363.93

Answer (score 3):

You can do that manually.  Navigate to the following locations to find the Start Menu shortcuts:

> Your Start Menu - **%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs**
>
> All users Start Menu - **%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs**

Once you arrive in those folders, you can select any shortcut to easily copy/paste to your desktop.

Comment: That's a smart solution, thank you. I wonder why ms removed this option.

Comment: Always glad to help!  Music2myear is one of Super User's very best contributors, and his assessment is exactly right:  the Start Menu within this version of Windows really is rather dynamic, so unfortunately some functions aren't quite as simple as they used to be.

Comment: Awwww shucks @Run5k. You're making me blush. Pedro, as an IT pro I think it would be nice if they left well-enough alone, but when they're trying to integrate apps and traditional programs into the same interface in a way that works consistently for all users, they did have to make some adjustments, and this was one of them.

Comment: For a program added by the Microsoft Store, it doesn't seem to be in either of these locations (Windows 10).   Using the task manager, the executable seems to be kept in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps (which isn't normally accessible).   Searching the intertubes, the answer is go open the Run dialog (WINKEY + R), type shell:AppsFolder and then click OK.  The right click on the app downloaded from the Microsoft Store and choose create shortcut. It will say "can't do it here" and ask if you want to create it on the desktop.  Say yes and you're done.

Answer (score -3):

If you find the app you want on the start menu and then hold down AltGr and CTRL and then drag the icon to a folder it will give a little pop up saying copy link here and you click on that and it will copy the link.

Comment: What is AltGr ?  Alt Green?